# Python: Reassigning Object to Class with No Constructor Does Not Overwrite Dictionary Field

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, constructor, overwrite

I'm using `Python 3.9.1` and am confused how Python's default constructor works.

I have the below class with a `Dictionary` field and no Constructor.

When I populate its `Dictionary` and then reassign my object to a new instance, the dictionary retains its existing value (this also happens for `List` fields):

```
from typing import Dict


class MyClass:
    records: Dict[str, str] = {}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_class = MyClass()
    print(my_class.records)  # prints `{}`.

    my_class.records['1'] = 'one'
    print(my_class.records)  # prints `{'1': 'one'}`.

    # This does not overwrite `my_class` with a new instance.
    # `records` still contains the above element.
    my_class = MyClass()
    print(my_class.records)  # prints `{'1': 'one'}`.
```

However, when I add a constructor, it works as expected:

```
from typing import Dict


class MyClass:
    records: Dict[str, str] = {}

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.records = {}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_class = MyClass()
    print(my_class.records)  # prints `{}`.

    my_class.records['1'] = 'one'
    print(my_class.records)  # prints `{'1': 'one'}`.

    # `my_class` is now overwritten and `records` has been set to `{}`.
    my_class = MyClass()
    print(my_class.records)  # prints `{}`
```

I was under the impression that Python's default constructor would use the fields I have declared in the class (`records: Dict[str, str] = {}` in this case) to overwrite the existing object.

What doubly confuses me is that when I work with a regular field (`string` in the below case, but it also works for custom classes), I don't need a constructor to overwrite the field:

```
class MyClass:
    field: str = ''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_class = MyClass()
    print(my_class.field)  # prints nothing.

    my_class.field = 'some value'
    print(my_class.field)  # prints `some value`.

    # `field` has been reset to '' even though `MyClass` has no constructor.
    my_class = MyClass()
    print(my_class.field)  # prints nothing.
```

Can someone explain what Python is doing?

Comment: "when using a string, I don't need a constructor to overwrite the field" - yes. Because you **overwrite** the field/object. And in case with the dictionary, you're not doing that. Instead. you're changing the state of the same dictionary.

Comment: Could you add this as a potential answer, but with more info? Specifically, why is the dictionary field's state being changed instead of it being overwritten? And thanks for answering!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Specifically, why is the dictionary field's state being changed instead of it being overwritten?

Because you're not assigning to records. You're just reading it. This

```
my_class.records['1'] = 'one'
```

is equivalent to this

```
d = my_class.records
d['1'] = 'one'
```

Also, this is why adding that constructor makes the code "work". Because in it, you're reassigning `records`.

```
self.records = {}
```

Comment: Ah, so it's just how Python Dictionary and List fields work? Credit to the user who posted an answer here and deleted it for this info (their username was like `qofy` or something), but when I print `id(my_class.records))` vs `id(my_class.field))`, the id for `records` is always the same while the id for `field` always changes, supporting your answer that the Dictionary field is indeed being reused instead of overwritten.

Answer (score 2):

It is a great topic to touch on and it is encountered mostly while starting learning basic data types in python. *You know the buzz- everything is an object*

---

#### Now to the solution:

The problem you are facing is because of 2 reasons.

1. Mutability
2. Class variable

Let's explore.
In the first code where you demonstrated... let me show you (trimmed code)

```
class MyClass:
    records: Dict[str, str] = {}

my_class = MyClass()
print(my_class.records)  # prints `{}`.
```

Here two things happened, first a variable called 'record' created with the data type of `Dict`, in the class space. Secondly it is a mutable datatype.

And in the second example where you shown the `str` datatype, it is immutable.
And, here is where the trick happens.

The way python works sometimes confuse you. First, these are the immutable and mutable types that will give you the same behaviour respectively:

**Immutable Object**: int, float, long, complex, string tuple, bool
**Mutable Object**: list, dict, set, byte array, user-defined classes

---

↓ Instead of making it too confusing. Consider this ↓

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a
a[0] = 111

# Now?
b
>>> [111, 2, 3]
```

```
#But
a = (1, 2, 3)
b = a
a = (111, 2, 3)

b
>>> (1, 2, 3)
```

I guess this is well known, but this exact principle behind the scenes is going on with your case.

Here you can also check that in the immutable objects the id changes but in mutable, it doesn't.

There are many things when python can fool us if we don't pay attention to simple things.
Read more on it [Amazing article focusing just on this](https://medium.com/@tyastropheus/tricky-python-i-memory-management-for-mutable-immutable-objects-21507d1e5b95)

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful answer! I wish I could accept multiple answers, as it's also pretty informative in its own right. I hope just an upvote is fine.